# ASP.Net Core 3.1 upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-3.1

I am in the process of upgrading an existing Asp.Net Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET core3 and have followed most of the steps necessary in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio to make that happen. There is an angular app attached, and I was having issues connecting to it from there, (the Core app is a web API project). I tried to start over with the upgrade from scratch, having to remove Swagger code from it as it isn't working and isn't necessary right now. I get this:

```
// http://localhost:{port}/

{
  "source": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core"
}
```

as the only thing on the page, and when I set up a Postman request to hit an Anon-Allowed GET action, it returns the same thing in the result, instead of the expected result.

I have converted services.AddMvc to services.AddControllers, in ConfigureServices => Startup.cs, and converted to use app.UseRouting, UseCors, UseAuthentication, and UseEndpoints, (in that order), in Configure => Startup.cs. I also set MapControllers inside the UseEndpoints method while defining the EndpointBuilder to pass in.

I know that it is not even hitting the method because I have placed a breakpoint at the beginning of it to see what happened and why it was returning an error and that result. That breakpoint does not get hit at all.

Comment: Not really sure what's going on, or why you're seeing a json dictionary with the web server's namespace. Turn on all the logging, add your own middleware so you can breakpoint / debug the pipeline....?